# Git saying branches are up-to-date while they are not

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have cloned a bitbucket repository, files were downloaded in the directory. And I found only files of master(main) branch were downloaded, there are two more branches in the repository and none of the commits from those two branches were downloaded during cloning. When I switch to those branches via `git checkout` and use `git pull` terminal says `already up-to-date` but nothing from those branches is up-to-date. Even the project is not running, because of missing those updates. `git` downloaded the project but not totally, I have used some more commands such as `$ git fetch origin other-branch && git merge other-branch` from other Stack Overflow questions but no changes. I only started using git, and I know only few commands. Could anybody explain simply how to solve this? I don't know whether I gave enough information to explain. `git branch -avv` gave me this:

`git branch -avv
  data-export                dbc2e32 [origin/data-export] resolve conflicts and merge data-export to master
* genset                     d93228b [origin/genset] Scoreboard with kilowatt hours
  master                     4089eb8 [origin/master] allow 31h meter config
  remotes/origin/HEAD        -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/data-export dbc2e32 resolve conflicts and merge data-export to master
  remotes/origin/genset      d93228b Scoreboard with kilowatt hours
  remotes/origin/master      4089eb8 allow 31h meter config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning again and only setting `git remote add origin` did help for that

Answer (score 1):

Those branches are downloaded during a [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).
Do a `git branch -avv` and you will see them: like `remotes/origin/abranch`.
(`abranch` is just an example here)

A `git checkout abranch` will automatically be linked to the remote tracking branch `origin/abranch`.

From [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

That explains:

> When I switch to those branches via `git checkout` and use `git pull` terminal says already up-to-date.

---

As the output of `git branch -av` shows, a `git checkout data-export` or `git checkout genset` has automatically linked those local branches to their upstream counterparts, the remote tracking branches `origin/data-export` and `origin/genset`.

Their SHA1 are identical, which is why a `git fetch` or `git pull` would return an "up-to-date" answer.

As soon as a commit is done on one of those branch, a `git push` will succeed in updating that same branch on the remote `origin` repo.
See the [full discussion here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89459/discussion-between-developer-and-vonc).

Comment: `git checkout abranch` saying the following:
error: pathspec 'abranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: @developer did you type 'abranch'? It is just an example.

Comment: But I did not understand what to do here. I have done `git chekcout <branchname>` before posting question, so I did it again but what should I do next ? `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>` ? what does `<remote>` stands for?

Comment: @developer start by typing `git branch -avv`, and put its output in your question. As for the --track option, did you read the doc I mention in my answer? It says it would ** treat as equivalent** a `git checkout abranch` and a `--track origin/abranch` (here `<remote>` would refer to `origin`), if `origin/abranch` was one of the remote branches cloned from `origin`.

Comment: I added the output to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89459/discussion-between-developer-and-vonc).